# Cache the results of two methods in a single cache in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-cache

I have two methods, the first returning a list of elements and the second returning a single element:

```
List<User> getUsersFromExternalSystem(List<Integer> userIds);
User getUserFromExternalSystem(Integer userId);
```

I would like Spring to cache the results of these two methods, so that when the list of elements method (`getUsersFromExternalSystem()`) is called it caches the results for the provided ids (`userIds`) and when the single element method (`getUserFromExternalSystem()`) is called with the id previously provided to the list of elements method it uses the cache.

I can simply apply `@Cacheable` to these methods, then (if I understand correctly) when I call:

```
getUsersFromExternalSystem(Arrays.asList(1, 2))
```

the results will be cached but when I call

```
getUserFromExternalSystem(1);
```

the cache will not be used. How this be done in Spring?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following approach. Only first method `getUser(Integer id)` is cacheable, and second method just combines the results of `getUser` invocations.

```java
@Service
@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
class UserService {

    private final UserService self;

    @Autowired
    public UserService(UserService userService) {
        self = userService;
    }

    @Cacheable(cacheNames = "users", key = "id") // assuming that you've already initialized Cache named "users"
    public User getUser(Integer id) {
        return new User(); // ... or call to some DataSource
    }

    public List<User> getUsers(List<Integer> ids) {
        List<User> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Integer id : ids) {
            list.add(self.getUser(id));
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

The trick with injecting a bean into himself and calling

`self.getUser(id)` instead of `this.getUser(id)`

is required because `@Cacheable` will be actually invoked only when used on a Spring proxied bean, and `this` is not a proxy. More details here [Transactions, Caching and AOP: understanding proxy usage in Spring](http://spring.io/blog/2012/05/23/transactions-caching-and-aop-understanding-proxy-usage-in-spring)

Comment: thanks, but that is not what i want - i want to call `users()` and reuse the cache when `user()` is called; not when users() is called, call `user()` for each user